# Why is ROS ANSWERS forum so easily exploitable?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS ANSWERS unlike stackexchange, ubuntu forums is easily exploitable and I want to divert the attention of forum moderators to this issue.
In this forum anybody can make an account and upvote answers or ask any questions. You do not need certain amount of karma to upvote questions so I can make as many accounts as I want. Also one does not need email verification to set up an account for this forum. I can use this forum on someone else's email account and will encounter no problems or restrictions.
I just care about this community so wanted to share my opinion. I hope the moderators understand although I do realize that this does not have many disadvantages but still.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68941/why-is-ros-answers-forum-so-easily-exploitable?/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every barrier to entry makes it harder for both spammers and regular users.  We tune the settings to make it as easy as possible to join the community without being overloaded with spam.  So far we don't have a problem, if you see a problem please use the flag offensive button and contact the administrators using the "give feedback" link at the bottom.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2013-08-27**:
where is the flag offensive button?!?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-28**:
It is at the bottom of all questions and answers next to the edit links.  They may be restricted to people with a minimum of karma.

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2013-08-30**:
thanks, I guess it is since I don't see them :-)

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-08**:
What's the minimum karma for flagging posts? 1000 seems not enough. Maybe worth lowering it and adding this info to http://answers.ros.org/faq/.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-08**:
The minimum for flagging a post is 5 Karma.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-08**:
Looks like I need to get my glasses checked ... I only see `edit`, `delete`, `link`, `retag` and `close`. Maybe sth needs to be enabled to let non-admins use this function?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-08**:
if you don't see it please open a ticket at https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org to track it.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-09**:
Done. https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/49